# jQuery 1.9.0 breaks $.attrFn object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a library of useful 'mobile' events ([available here](https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events)). It essentially unifies touch events so that a single event can be bound to an element, and it will trigger regardless of the user's device (i.e. mobile or desktop).

The code has been working well, but while debugging a user's problem, I noticed that the library no longer functions when jQuery 1.9.0 is used (all previous versions of jQuery don't cause a problem).

The problematic code is as follows:

```
// Add Event shortcuts:
$.each(('tapstart tapend tap singletap doubletap taphold swipe swipeup swiperight swipedown swipeleft scrollstart scrollend orientationchange').split(' '), function(i, name)      {
    $.fn[name] = function(fn)
    {
        return fn ? this.bind(name, fn) : this.trigger(name);
    };
    $.attrFn[name] = true;
});
```

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'tapstart' of undefined` on the following line:

`$.attrFn[name] = true;`

Can anyone point me in the direction of producing a fix for this?

I have put together 2 jsFiddle demos to show the problem:

- [Working version](http://jsfiddle.net/9J3Qw/3/) (using jQuery 1.8.3)
- [Non-working version](http://jsfiddle.net/9J3Qw/4/) (using jQuery 1.9.0)

If I define `$.attrFn`, this fixes code for the `swipe*` events, but then causes problems with others such as `tap` and `doubletap`. For example, binding `tap` now produces the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined`, with the problematic line being:

```
$.event.handle.call( obj, event );
```

Once again, there are two jsFiddles for reference:

- [Working version](http://jsfiddle.net/9J3Qw/6/) (using jQuery 1.8.3)
- [Non-working version](http://jsfiddle.net/9J3Qw/7/) (using jQuery 1.9.0 with `$.attrFn = $.attrFn || {};` fix)

Comment: If you check the 1.8 source code, it's pretty obvious :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That object (`.attrFn`) was just a stub in 1.8; it's gone in 1.9.

If your code worked in 1.8, you should be able to add

```
$.attrFn = $.attrFn || {};
```

somewhere to fix it.

Comment: ... or of course just don't do the update if the property isn't there.

Comment: It works fine for `swipe*` events, but if we try adding in a tap, now a different error occurs. Please see my updated question. +1 for the help here, mind you.

Comment: @BenM Well note (from epascarello's answer) that `$.event.handle()` is also gone.  Check the 1.8 source and see what it did with it.  This should be a useful lesson in why it's a bad idea to depend on undocumented properties/methods of jQuery :-)

Comment: **READ THE CHANGE DOC!** Same reason as before!

Comment: Thank you, I missed the omission of the `event.handle()` method too. No need to shout, @epascarello!

Comment: @epascarello Shouting without providing a link mmmmm

Answer (score 9):

[From the jQuery 1.9 Release Notes](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

> **Other undocumented properties and methods**
>
> The following internal properties and methods were never documented and have been removed in 1.9. Any code that depends on them
>   should be rewritten.
>
> - jQuery.deletedIds
> - jQuery.uuid
> - **jQuery.attrFn**
> - jQuery.clean()
> - jQuery.event.handle()
> - jQuery.offset.bodyOffset()

Comment: Unfortunately, jquerymobile seems to use it still.  Not sure how to fix that besides patching it locally.  That may make it work for dev/test, but no good for release.

Comment: @GerryGleason Are you on the latest version of jQuery mobile? They should support the latest and greatest version of jQuery. If not, file a bug with them.

Comment: jQuery Mobile 1.4+ doesn't actually use attrFn, it checks if it exists to determine the version of jQuery. If you're using jQueryMigrate, it will generate a false warning. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5984.

Comment: Can you please give an example how jQuery.attrFn work? I got the same warning `jQuery.attrFn is deprecated` and didn't get any function with string 'attrFn'. So, confused, am i searching right ?